# a custom event for pressing the 'Enter key' in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a UserControl with some controls and a textbox on it, i want to do some procedures when the Enter key hits on that textbox, I have this code in the UserControl:

```
public event EventHandler TextBoxKeyPressed
{
    add { textBox.KeyPressed+=value; }
    remove { textBox.KeyPressed-=value; }
}
```

in my main form I have a lot of this control and for each one I should check for the key pressed and if it was Enter key then do the procedures.

Is there any way to create a custom event to check the key pressed in the UserControl and if it was Enter Key then fire that event?

Update: each custom control may have different procedures on KeyPresssd event

Comment: If you need to Bubble the event to the parent control afterwards have a look at this http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051105-1.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can just add, say, an EnterPressed event and fire it when you detect that the Enter key was pressed:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl {
    public event EventHandler EnterPressed;

    public UserControl1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.KeyDown += textBox1_KeyDown;
    }

    protected void OnEnterPressed(EventArgs e) {
        var handler = this.EnterPressed;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
            OnEnterPressed(EventArgs.Empty);
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event doesn't change, it would still be a normal key pressed event.  You'd simply only perform the intended action therein if the key was the enter key.  Something like this:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        // the enter key was pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but keyPressed event for each textBox is different :-)

Comment: @AliTheOne: You can use the same `if` conditional in each one.  Or, if the logic is the same for all of them, you can use the same event for each `TextBox`.